# How to get mingw64 to work with codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I'm trying to get the latest mingw64 working with codeblocks 17.12. I have setup the global compiler settings correctly (as per here:https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/code-blocks-compile-64-bit-under-windows-with-mingw-w64-79101f5bbc02). The project I'm trying to compile fails at _beginthreadex. If I compile using the MinGW that comes with codeblocks it works fine (at least it doesn't fail at that point).
Anyone know what might be the problem?
This is the log:

```
C:\backup\warlord\Warlord\Warlord\FightScreen.cpp: In member function 'void FightScreen::StartLoading()':
C:\backup\warlord\Warlord\Warlord\FightScreen.cpp:444:21: error: '_beginthreadex' was not declared in this scope
  m_handle = (void *)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &LoadInThread, 0, 0, 0);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\backup\warlord\Warlord\Warlord\FightScreen.cpp:444:21: note: suggested alternative: 'OpenThread'
  m_handle = (void *)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &LoadInThread, 0, 0, 0);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     OpenThread
```

Comment: Where did you get mingw64  from?

Comment: Unrelated: Can we talk you out of `_beginthreadex` and into `std::thread`?

Comment: Looks like you are missing an include. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx says you need `#include <process.h>`

Comment: I agree with @user4581301 you should use `std::thread` anyways.

Comment: Thanks drescherjm, that was it, missing #include <process.h>. It's funny none of the other compilers complained about that

Comment: Maybe some other system header you have pulled it in on the older compiler.

Comment: I included only <windows.h> and neither MinGW or the VC compiler complained. Doesn't matter anyway